# Android: custom view from inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am creating my own layout based on `RelativeLayout` as a class in code

I have basics of the layout defined in XML `R.layout.menu_layout` (style, drawable for background, margin, height)

If I would not need a class then I would call inflater to do this:

```
RelativeLayout menuLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, root);
```

But I would like to be calling my own class instead

```
MenuLayout menuLayout = new MenuLayout(myparams);
```

Since I need to create a class I need to somehow inherit the `R.layout.menu_layout` in constructor, how can I do that? I guess there is no `this.setLayout(res);` or `this.setResource(res);` in View. Maybe I can use the other two parameters in View constructor but I did not find any tutorial how to do that either.

Comment: can you rephrase a bit your question ?

Comment: did the new info help?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MenuLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public MenuLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    public MenuLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public MenuLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        addView(view);
    }
}
```

now you can use

```
MenuLayout menuLayout = new MenuLayout(myparams);
```

you can change constructors for params i think

Comment: doesnt that just put a relative layout into a relative layout? I was thinking of this as an work-around as well but I was hoping for some cleaner way

Comment: Yes it does but this is what i came up with. I think it's a clean and easy to understand solution. It might be improved because of the unnecessary `RelativeLayout`.