# OnClick Listeners in include layout

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout which contains an edittext and two button for increment and decrement of the value in editext. Now I am using `include` to use this button in my `activity` as I am having multiple use of that.

eg :-

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/editTextOne"
    layout="@layout/include_edittext_with_buttons"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <include
    android:id="@+id/editTextTwo"
    layout="@layout/include_edittext_with_buttons"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I can get the `onClick` events of my `increment` and `decrement` buttons but I don't understand how will i catch that the `onClick` of the particular `include` has been clicked. ?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/editText" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/editText" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

NOTE :- I get that working using `binding. editTextOne.btnPlus.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Plus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }` and similar for the other's but what i want is I can write the `plus` and `minus` click listener once and then they update the values of the `edittext` in which they are included only.

Not sure if that would be possible any better suggestions ?

Comment: Can you share include_edittext_with_buttons layout file?

Comment: Don't use include Id to attach events on buttons, use button's or layout Ids to attach onClickListener.

Comment: @Ekrem added code

Comment: @hafiza am already using button id's that's what causing problem as I have same layout included multiple times if i click on first layout's plus button then also it will trigger the second layouts plus button as they are similar

Comment: What I would do in your case is create a function that gets a view (of the specific one you are including) that will init it's functionality. That way, each click of a button will belong only to the relevant children of the specific layout and will save lots of coding (unless you need specific behavior for each layout you are including)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a solution for solving this problem.
first, assign an id for each of the includes.

```
 <include
       android:id="@+id/inc1"
       layout="@layout/include_layout" 
        ...
  />


  <include
       android:id="@+id/inc2"
       layout="@layout/include_layout"
        ...
  />
```

then add oclick in view's xml code.

//include_layout.xml"

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    ...
   />
```

after implementing onClick function in your code you can specify which view exactly clicked by checking its parent id.

```java
    

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.ib) {

            int parent_id = ((View) view.getParent()).getId();

            if (parent_id == R.id.inc1) {
              //clicked view in first include          
            } 
            else if (parent_id == R.id.inc2) {
             //clicked view in second include
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Your solution is perfect and works as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get views like that.

```
    // First View
    val includedView1 = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.editTextOne)

    val btnPlus1 = includedView1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnPlus)
    val btnMinus1 = includedView1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnMinus)

    // Second View
    val includedView2 = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.editTextTwo)

    val btnPlus2 = includedView2.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnPlus)
    val btnMinus2 = includedView2.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnMinus)
```

Comment: Yap I know I can get using this but that would be a lot of code to do if I have like four to five edittext although the use of both the buttons are same which is to update the edittext present in their own layout.

Comment: Maybe you can use custom views. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17413018/7937174