# Can we actually create 2 drawableLeft in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I was wondering if there is a way using which we can create 2 `drawableLeft` in our android layout. I have a scenario where i need to use 2 `drawables`. Anyone with any suggestions, drop them down please.

Edit: This is the layout that i want to design.

[image: layout]

Comment: you can join two drawables and set as one or just make more complex layout, e.g. horizontal `LinearLayout` with two `ImageView`s and `TextView`

Comment: No, you can't use 2 **drawableLeft** . But you can create Custom views.
Please share some example of what you want.

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee Updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this view in only one place then you could just use LinearLayout with horizontal layout. and place 1 ImageView, TextView or Spinner [as per your requirement if the country code is selectable then you should use spinner instead of TextView for country code view] TextView and style them as needed. As in following picture:

[image]

If you need to use this layout in multiple place you could implement Custom View with the same layout file. Check how to create Custom View from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54000985/6395022).